# Докачка файлов в браузере

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вот возникло два похожих  вопроса, можно ли скачивать и загружать на сервер файлы с докачкой, если да то где почитать про это, сервер подразумевается самописный на Node.js
ps: и чтобы была при этом хоть какая-то кроссбраузерность, то есть вариант только IE или только Chrome не очень подходит.

Comment: Загружать - тут будут сложности и по поддержке браузерами, и в плане реализации. А вот скачивание можно сделать. Даже если у ноды встроенных средств для этого нет, то можно достаточно легко написать.

Comment: Боюсь если скрипт будет поддерживать скачку/докачку файла - то это будет боольшая **дыра** в безопасности. Тут речь идёт о http-протоколе и его модификациях, сам протокол должен это поддерживать (по-моему этой поддержки нету). Дозагрузку если кто и должен реализовывать то лишь браузер и то по елементу input+file

Comment: Поддержка должна быть с обоих сторон, и браузеру и серверу надо понимать что часть файла уже обработана и не надо слать его весь, я конечно слабо верю в то что такое есть, просто я больше по Node.Js и браузерный JS не очень глубоко знаю

Comment: @nick_n_a Скачивание по частям протокол поддерживает (см. HTTP-заголовок `Range`). С закачкой сложнее.

Comment: @nick_n_a, http поддерживает докачку. Это accept-ranges и range.

Comment: Как я понимаю сделать поддержку докачки upload'а в принципе легко, на стороне сервера у нас всё есть и в браузере в FileAPI вроде есть что нам нужно, а вот поддержка докачивания в скачивании, тут проблема в том как склеить файл, тот кусок что скачался и тот что докачиваем.

Comment: @vnn198, полностью наоборот.

Comment: Почему? в браузере в JS File API можно получить уникальный идентификатор файла и как я понял есть возможность чтения кусков файла, по сути нам нужно спросить у сервера сколько он получил из этого файла и начать докачивать то что осталось. Больше вопросов с докачкой файлов который я скачиваю с сервера, но там главная проблема получить доступ к недокачанному файлу на диске